# Defining conversion from a class to double

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I was wondering if there is a way to pull this off, or at least, a better way to do this completely with templates:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
double sum(const vector<T>& vt, const vector<U>& vu)
{
    // . . .
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        sum += convert(vt[i] * vu[i]);
    return sum;
}
```

`T` and `U` are supposed to be numbers like double, int or any other class that supports these operations (I'm new to templates).

Is there any way to get rid of this `convert()` function (which gets the number member of a specific class) and just write `sum += vt[i] * vu[i]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are a bit hopeful.

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename resultType = double >
resultType sum(const vector<T>& vt, const vector<U>& vu)
{
    // . . .
    resultType sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vt.size(); ++i) {
        // two versions of sum - coerced to resultType before and after
        // multiplication
        sum += static_cast<resultType>(vt[i]) * static_cast<resultType>(vu[i]);
        sum += static_cast<resultType>(vt[i] * vu[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The 2 versions of `sum+=` will produce different results.  If sum were an integer, then truncation could occur.

In the multiplication between double and int, then type promotion occurs in one, but are normalized in the other.

### Update

With resultType = double
T and U are double - then the results are the same.

T is integer U is double.  T gets promoted to double, the results are the same.

T and U are integer.    `sum += static_cast<double>( vt[i] * vu[i] );` multiplies the integers, possibly overflowing and returning a different result.

With resultType = int

T and U are double - the result is either the integer truncation of the number, or the integer truncation of the result.

static_cast( 5.3) * static_cast( 3.7); => 15

static_cast( 5.3 *  3.7); => static_cast( 19.61) => 19

T is integer U is double.  As above
T and U are integer.    Both are consistent.

With a class and a

```
operator double() const { return value; }
```

as suggested in the other posts, then the first sum += will work, where as the second relies on at least one numeric type, so the compiler can try the explicit `double` conversion.

With two `class` then the `sum += static_cast<resultType>(vt[i]) * static_cast<resultType>(vu[i]);` will succeed in finding the double operator, but the `sum += static_cast<resultType>(vt[i]) * static_cast<resultType>(vu[i]);` will fail.

Also a function such as

```
operator *( const class X &lhs, const class U & rhs )
{

    return static_cast<double>(lhs) * static_cast<double>(rhs);
}
```

Would help the compiler.

Comment: What is the difference between those two versions?

Comment: @user3650284 Is there a chance that both `T` and `U` are integers? If yes, how are you storing the return value? If as `double`, why?

Comment: I chose double because I didn't know how to do the version with the templates. There is a chance that both are integers. I'm just curious what is the difference between those versions?

Comment: Although you gave me these two versions, I get the same result every time (tried your example with 5.3 * 3.7, I get 19 always).

Answer (score 3):

If you define implicit conversion operators to `double` (or one to `double` and other to type that can be promoted to `double`) for all `T` and `U`, `vt[i]` and `vu[i]` will be converted to `double`s, and the result of multiplication will be `double`, just as you want.

Example:

```
class Foo
{
    double value;

public:
    // ...

    operator double() const { return value; }
};
```

But you must decide what to return.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use The inner_product() algorithm that is defined in the numeric header?

The inner product algorithm calculates the inner product of two sequences of the same length. Type of value returned is determined by the fourth argument.

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip> 

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<double> a{0, 1.1, 2, 3.1, 4};
    vector<int> b{5, 4, 2, 3, 1};

    double r1 = inner_product(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), 0.0);
    cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed)  << std::setprecision(5)
              << "Inner product of a and b: " << r1 << '\n';


}
```

Comment: 1. The containers don't have to be of the same size. 2. I am not using only built-in types.

Comment: @user3650284 The second b range and has as many elements as the range above  b = [begin(a), end(a)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to write `sum += vt[i] * vu[i];` then the product of `T` and `U` must be defined, either by defining an *ad-hoc* product returning `double` for these types, by providing a `double` conversion operator on those types, or some combination of these.